# Creating a stack in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, stack

I am working on an RPN calculator for the iPhone using iOS 5 for a programming assignment and I am not sure how to create a stack in Objective-C to push numbers onto. I could use a little help with this part, as the rest of the application is working out fine.

Comment: The simplest way is to wrap an NSMutableArray and add Push and Pop functionality.

Comment: @nonamelive suggestion is bang on. You don't need to even subclass it, just use the built in addObject to push and combine lastObject (to get the last object) and removeLastObject (to remove it from the array) for pop functionality

Comment: Note that, to use an NSMutableArray, the "numbers" should be implemented as NSNumber, rather than using primitive ints/floats/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)operandStack // override the getter for lazy instantiation
{
    if (!_operandStack)
    {
        [self setOperandStack:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    }

    return _operandStack;
}


-(void)pushOperand:(double)operand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
    [[self operandStack] addObject:operandObject];
}


-(double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [[self operandStack] lastObject];

    if (operandObject)
    {
        [[self operandStack] removeLastObject];
        return [operandObject doubleValue];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```